# How to print a index inside a map in React component?

Tags: reactjs, indexing, array.prototype.map

I'm quite new to React. Could someone help me print an index using the `console.log` function in this mapping? Many thanks in advance

```
{projectData.map((_, index) => (
    <button
    key={index}`
    onClick={() => goToSlide(index)}
    className={index === currentIndex ? 'active slider-button' : 'slider-button'}>
    { `Project ${index + 1}` }
    </button>
 ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use return keyword to console.log(index)

```html
{projectData.map((_, index) => {
    console.log(index);
    return (
      <button
        key={index}`
        onClick={() => goToSlide(index)}
        className={index === currentIndex ? 'active slider-button' : 'slider-button'}>
        { `Project ${index + 1}` }
      </button>
    )
 })}
```